# Month conversion to words

Tags: datetime, php

I have dates stored in array for completion status of projects like below

The first two letters are months and other four letters are years

052012(mmyyyy)

```
$arrDates = array('052012', '042013', '082013', '122013', '022014');
```

I want this array To get converted to wordings as below

```
$arrDates = array('Completed', 'Next Six Months', 'Next Year', 'Next Year', 'After 2 Years');
```

I used a for loop like below for checking completed as below

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arrDates);$i++)
{
  if((date('m') > substr($arrDates[$i], 0,2)) && (date('y') == substr($arrDates[$i], 2,6)))           
  $strStatus = ' Completed';
}
```

and I messed up in finding for next year and other two.

Could some one help me in fixing this?

Comment: Please clarify on what is the available set of wordings (are those 4 cases all there can be? is the last case generic - i.e. 'After $x years'?). And what are the rules of their application? E.g. what happens if the date falls both under 'Next 6 month' and 'Next year'? (Assuming 'Next year' means 'next calendar year' as opposed to 'next 12 months from now'). What if it does not fall under any case (E.g. now is Feb 12, 2012 and the date is 122012? It's the same calendar year, but >6 months in the future).

Comment: Only four Cases Not any thing more than that.If the Date falls under next 6 months and Next year it should be considered as Next 6 Months.Now is Feb 12, 2012 and the date is 122012? - Its should be shown as completed

Comment: "Now is Feb 12, 2012 and the date is 122012?" - no, it's not completed, it's in the future - in fact 10 months in the future (i.e. >6 months but still the same year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `DateTime` and `dateInterval` for this :

```
$currentDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('mY',$arrDates[0]);
$interval = $currentDate->diff(new DateTime('now'),true);
if($interval->invert){
   echo 'Completed';
else if($interval->y >= 2 ){
   echo 'After 2 Years';
}
else if($interval->y == 1){
   echo 'Next Year';
}
else if($interval->m > 6){
   echo 'what you want here';
}
else {
   echo 'Next six months';
}
```

Comment: @artragis the idea of your solution seems good. But.. 1) `elseif` is a single word in PHP; 2) I don't see why you have so complicated case for 'After 2 years' - a simple `$interval->y >= 2` would suffice, as now you are mishandling the case where y=2 and m=0 -- you would return  'Next six months' in such case; 3) You are missing quite a few closing curly brackets (better code style would help to spot this more easily)

Comment: in php elseif and else if are the same world.
I will edit about the 2 years 
idem for curly brackets

Comment: what does "it's not working mean"? Now that I've edited my answer, is it working?

Answer (score 0):

I think artragis was on the right track with his answer (+1 for that), but the whole thing should be encapsulated in a function for re-use.

```
/**
 * @param string $expectedDate
 * @return string Text summary of time to completion
 */
function completionTimeInWords($expectedDate)
{
    $now = new DateTime();
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimestamp(strtotime('+1 year'));
    $oneYear = $date->diff($now)->days;
    $sixMonths = round($oneYear/2);
    $date->setTimestamp(strtotime('+2 years'));
    $twoYears = $date->diff($now)->days;

    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('mY', $expectedDate);
    $interval = $now->diff($date);
    $completed = (bool)$interval->invert;
    $days = $interval->days;
    if($completed){
        return 'Completed';
    } elseif($days <= $sixMonths){
        return 'Next Six Months';
    } elseif($days > $sixMonths && $days <= $oneYear){
        return 'Within a year';
    } elseif($days > $oneYear && $days <= $twoYears){
        return 'Next Year';
    } elseif($days > $twoYears){
        return 'After Two Years';
    }
}
```

I tested this with the following code:-

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(strtotime('two weeks ago'));
$arrDates[] = $date->format('mY');
$date->setTimestamp(strtotime('+ 5 months 27 days'));
$arrDates[] = $date->format('mY');
$date->setTimestamp(strtotime('+ 6 months 4 days'));
$arrDates[] = $date->format('mY');
$date->setTimestamp(strtotime('+ 12 months 4 days'));
$arrDates[] = $date->format('mY');
$date->setTimestamp(strtotime('+ 24 months 4 days'));
$arrDates[] = $date->format('mY');
foreach($arrDates as $date){
    var_dump(completionTimeInWords($date));
}
```

and got the following output:-

```
string(9) "Completed"
string(15) "Next Six Months"
string(13) "Within a year"
string(9) "Next Year"
string(15) "After Two Years"
```

You may need to do some more testing with edge cases as these can be problematic. For example, most of us would agree that 6 months is 183 days, but PHP may disagree on occasion depending on how many days are in each month between now and 6 months hence (if that makes sense). That is why I have divided a year by 2 to get 6 months, rather than using `strtotime()`.

Comment: I did not use a function because I can't know if he is using POO, if this name is not reserved in his app... I provided the functionnal code, and he has to insert it the cleanest way in his app.

Comment: about php behaviour with relative dates. (and please do not use strtotime, DateTime understands relative format...). You are wrong a month is not 30 days, it is 28-29-30 or 31 days. PHP has the good behaviour.

Comment: @artragis I don't say a month is 30 days. POO?

Comment: POO = OOP in french, it's just a typo... 
6 month = 183 days says 3 months of 31 days + 3 months of 30 days. It is quite false. Php os true  for that